# Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.github.YUNEEC:Yuneec-SDK-Android:vX.Y.Z

Tags: android

There are some problems with my build.gradle(app). I'm trying to programms a drone but i can't do anything because of this error. In fact i don't have access do the repo for the version in the end of the line conserned.

```js
ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.github.YUNEEC.Yuneec-SDK-Android:sdk:3.5.2.
Show Details
Affected Modules: app


ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.github.YUNEEC.Yuneec-SDK-Android:sdk:3.5.2.
Show Details
Affected Modules: app


ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.github.YUNEEC.Yuneec-SDK-Android:sdk:3.5.2.
Show Details
Affected Modules: app
```

Here's dependecies section of my build.gradle

```js
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    implementation 'com.github.YUNEEC:Yuneec-SDK-Android:v3.5.2'
}
```

Comment: did you follow their instructions on how to add the dependancy?